# Div with position fixed until certain height glitching

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, position

I'm having trouble fixing a script that scrolls down with the page and stops on a specific height. Right before it reaches the point it needs to be on position absolute again, it disappears for a moment and appears right after.

Here's an example of [the code](http://jsfiddle.net/xhnLsqrr):

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y > 280 && y < 1600) {
        $('#model').css("position","fixed");
        $('#icons').css("position","fixed");
        $('#icons').css("bottom",0);
    } else if (y >= 1601) {
        $('#model').css("position","absolute");
        $('#model').css("top",1600);
        $('#icons').css("position","absolute");
        $('#icons').css("top",1600);
    } else {
        $('#model').removeAttr( 'style' );
        $('#icons').removeAttr( 'style' );
        $('#icons').removeAttr( 'style' );
    }   
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *glitch* that you are referring to might be caused by either of the two conditions:

1. For the first condition, you have a scrollTop range between `280` & `1599` (`< 1600`), and further `>= 1601`. This leaves a *blank* area on the scrollTop position `1600` itself.
2. When you scroll back from the bottom to top, the `#model` div's top is not set back to the original state (`0`), and it somehow wanders to it's containers boundaries I suppose.

Therefore, the following changes in your code should fix the issue:

```
if (y > 280 && y < 1600) {
    $('#model').css("position","fixed");
    $('#model').css('top', 0);          // add this rule
    $('#icons').css("position","fixed");
    $('#icons').css("bottom",0);
} else if (y >= 1600) {                 // change the condition to include range greater than or equal to 1600
    $('#model').css("position","absolute");
    $('#model').css("top",1600);
    $('#icons').css("position","absolute");
    $('#icons').css("top",1600);
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/yz8L4gw1/).